# AppleScript & bit.ly API

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, url

New to AppleScript and coding. First Script I'm trying to compile:

1. Selecting and Copy URL in current Safari tab
2. Sending it to bit.ly
3. Having the shortened URL copied to clipboard

```
property theURL : ""
property bitlyToken : "0c60279f1425ac413d021f797d8c96f7dc5834af"

tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
    set the clipboard to theURL
end tell

set shellScript to 
("curl --url "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten" --data "access_token=" & bitlyToken & "&format=txt&longUrl=" & theURL & "" ")
```

Code is not compiling and I can't figure out if I'm adding a ShellScript or not implementing the bit.ly dev API code properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a surfeit of quotes and your internal quotes need escaping. Try this:

```
set shellScript to ("curl --url \"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten\" ¬
--data access_token=" & bitlyToken & "&format=txt&longUrl=" & theURL)
```

After this edit, it compiles and produces a curl command that appears complete.

I should add that you don't need the clipboard for anything you've done here, until after you've gotten the shortened url back.

```
set xyz to do shell script shellScript
set the clipboard to xyz
```

I get a 'forbidden' response. No clue why but I assume it's a bitly thing.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, compilation succesful.  Mainly missing that \ defining the URL.

In regards to the clipboard copying, absolutely, I was slowly building on each step, that was in regards to seeing if it would actually copy the current URL into a textfile, I just never appended it. 

Also got a forbidden response, am looking through the bit.ly documentation, it's a bit over my head but will see if I can trial and error some their documentation.

Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: You also had an extra `"` at the end. The `""` isn't needed but probably doesn't do any harm.

Comment: Ok accepted. Do you see anything glaringly wrong with the curl command as when i set the clipboard to shellScript I get something like this `curl --url "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten" ¬
--data access_token=0c60279f1425ac413d021f797d8c96f7dc5834af&format=txt&longUrl=https://www.bbc.com` which is the whole curl string? Should I open another Question to address that?

Comment: I'm not sure. I took a glance at the [bitly docs](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference/#createBitlink) and they have a couple of different options in the command. I'd take a look at that first to see if it makes sense.

Comment: You may also require a `group_guid`. It might be worthwhile to look at this answer which seems to go through the whole process — https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431375/7410243